# Xpages fileupload control and mime types

Tags: xpages

I have a problem uploading an image to a form field using the built in xpages fileuploader control. The form field the image is saved to is configured like explained in this blog post by Mats Knutsen: http://devxpages.blogspot.com/2011/03/display-picture-from-rich-text-field.html . I Also plan to display the image in an xpage using the template described in the blog post, like this (http://server/MyDatabase.nsf/viewunid/docunid/imageField/M2?OpenElement).

I know my fileuploader control points to the correct field in the form, since i can see the image in the document using the Lotus Notes Client after the document is created. However; the picture can not be viewed using "http://server/MyDatabase.nsf/viewunid/docunid/imageField/M2?OpenElement" at this point.

On the other hand, if I delete the field contents (the image) from the document field in the client, go back to the xpage with the fileuploader control, and uploads the image a second time, it works perfectly, and the image can be viewed using the url mentioned above.

When I access field properties after the first upload, the Data Type of my field is set to Rich Text.

The second time I upload the same image to the same field in the same document, the field properties Data Type is set to MIME Part, as it probably should have gotten the first time around as well.

Does anyone know why my file uploader control does not work the first time i upload the image, but when I edit the docuement and upload the image a second time, everything seems to be ok?

Comment: Is the option to store as MIME/HTML selected in the properties of the RTF?

Answer (score 3):

I would try to avoid uploading images into the RichText in the first place. Would it break your application if you resort to uploading the image as a regular attachment? You then can reference it using .../$File/imgfilename.jpg (using the file name used during upload - retrieved by @AttachmentNames)